# rfc-7616(HTTP Digest) example doesn't match

Tags: java, android, http, md5, digest

I'm strugling to implement HTTP Digest.

WWW-Authenticate header was tokenized as I expected mean while composing authorization header make me tortured.
I think everything is fine and no there's no reason it would be fault.

I was tried to change hash logic by searching web and also change uri form as full uri, only path or even  include scheme but result not much different.

Would you let me know what is wrong?
Save pathetic beginner...

rfc says the proper response is "8ca523f5e9506fed4657c9700eebdbec"  (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616#page-18)
but my program insist it would be "73999844ea00a1a065a5c4f0e0edc5f3]"

source code : https://github.com/dearblanc/HTTPDigestAndroid/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/kj/httpdigestandroid

rfc example...

3.9.  Examples

3.9.1.  Example with SHA-256 and MD5

The following example assumes that an access-protected document is
being requested from the server via a GET request.  The URI of the
document is "http://www.example.org/dir/index.html".  Both client and
server know that the username for this document is "Mufasa" and the
password is "Circle of Life" (with one space between each of the
three words).

...

```
   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
   ...
   WWW-Authenticate: Digest
   realm="http-auth@example.org",
   qop="auth, auth-int",
   algorithm=MD5,
   nonce="7ypf/xlj9XXwfDPEoM4URrv/xwf94BcCAzFZH4GiTo0v",
   opaque="FQhe/qaU925kfnzjCev0ciny7QMkPqMAFRtzCUYo5tdS"
```

...

```
   Authorization: Digest username="Mufasa",
   realm="http-auth@example.org",
   uri="/dir/index.html",
   algorithm=MD5,
   nonce="7ypf/xlj9XXwfDPEoM4URrv/xwf94BcCAzFZH4GiTo0v",
   nc=00000001,
   cnonce="f2/wE4q74E6zIJEtWaHKaf5wv/H5QzzpXusqGemxURZJ",
   qop=auth,
   response="8ca523f5e9506fed4657c9700eebdbec",
   opaque="FQhe/qaU925kfnzjCev0ciny7QMkPqMAFRtzCUYo5tdS"
```

Comment: Did you see https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid4495 ?

Comment: @JulianReschke Thanks, I didn't notice that.
But now it return "d142103549841c8d7adb7716345048f2" :(